# How to make turtle.onclick() case - "insensitive"?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to make a pong game using python turtle. I want the paddle to move using both uppercase and lowercase "w". Is there any technique to achieve this or do I have to write seperate statements for both uppercase and lowercase?

turtle.onclick(move_up, "w")

Answer (score 0):

You have to write:

```
turtle.onkeypress(move_up, 'w')
turtle.onkeypress(move_up, 'W')
turtle.onkeypress(move_down, 's')
turtle.onkeypress(move_down, 'S')
```

not:

```
turtle.onclick(move_up, "w")
```

`onclick` is when you want to get mouse info

And I think it is case-sensitive